handle WCF validation inside SOAP method
i have different SOAP call, all call have the request validated using DataAnnotation (es StringLength, Range etc etc)
I'm using ProvideFault to manage the validation error, but in this way the user get a different response. Can i avoid authomatic Validation ad manually validate the request inside the method to return a custom response?
Eg: if the user call CreateCustomer endpoint and expect CreateCustomerResponse.
I need something like
public CreateCustomerResponse CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerRequest request){
       var errors = validate(request)
       if(errors.any(){//hadle error}
       //do stuff


}


Try to use IParameterInspector Interface. The specific use needs to be analyzed on a case-by-case basis.

IparameterInspection methods are called AFTER the validation
